# Can you help me clear this error

Tags: c++, file-io

```
fstream file(Fname,ios::in|ios::binary);

pharmacy_personnel ob;
while(file.read((char*)ob,sizeof(ob)))
{
    total++;    
}
```

This is a small part of my code. It's giving an error that says:

> "no suitable conversion function from "pharmacy_personnel" to "char *" exists"

Please tell me where I have gone wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing an `&` (address-of) operator.

```
file.read((char *)&ob, sizeof ob)
```

Comment: ...assuming, of course, that the data in the file aligns with `pharmacy_personnel` objects.